# What is causing my "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Exception:

```
NoMethodError in CsdashboardController#index

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: /opt/csdashboard

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/csdashboard_controller.rb:106:in `index'
Request

Parameters:
None
```

Line 106 is

```
@dropdataitem = DropSeries.new(1, @data3[0]["fields"]["@timestamp"])
```

Here is the full class, sorry if its too much code.

```
class CsdashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @query_size = 500
    @esearch = Elasticsearch::Client.new :log => true
    @ts = DateTime.now - 30.days 
    if params[:query].present?
        @ts = DateTime.strptime(params[:ct], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M') unless params[:ct].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - params[:min].to_i.minutes unless params[:min].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - params[:hrs].to_i.hours unless params[:hrs].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - params[:days].to_i.days unless params[:days].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - 100.years unless params[:alltime].nil?

        @data = @esearch.search :q => (params[:query]), :size => @query_size
        @data = @data["hits"]["hits"]
        @data = @data.sort_by { |h| h["_source"]["@timestamp"] }.reverse!

        @filtered_data = Array.new
        if @data.count > 0
            @data.each do |d|
                break if d["_source"]["@timestamp"].to_time <  @ts
                @filtered_data.push(d) if d["_source"].has_key?("@message") || d["_source"].has_key?("message")
            end
        end

        render 'csdashboard/search'
    else
        # will render 'csdashboard/index'
        @widgets = Array.new
        @dropitems = Array.new
        @dropdataitems = Array.new

        @ts = DateTime.now - 30.days 
        @ts = DateTime.strptime(params[:ct], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M') unless params[:ct].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - params[:min].to_i.minutes unless params[:min].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - params[:hrs].to_i.hours unless params[:hrs].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - params[:days].to_i.days unless params[:days].nil?
        @ts = DateTime.now - 100.years unless params[:alltime].nil?

        @data3 = @esearch.search :body => {:query => {:term => {"@message" => "drop"}}, :size => @query_size, :fields => ["@message", "@timestamp"] }
        @data3 = @data3["hits"]["hits"]

        @dropdatahash = Hash.new(0)
        @data3.each do |dd| 
            break if dd["fields"]["@timestamp"].to_time <  @ts
            unless dd["fields"]["@message"].nil?
                ds = dd["fields"]["@timestamp"].to_date.strftime("%m/%Y")
                @dropdatahash[ds] += 1
            end
        end
        @ddhkeys = @dropdatahash.keys
        #@dropdatahash = @dropdatahash.sort_by { |k,v| k }.reverse!# _by { |k| k["key"] }

        @ddhkeys = @ddhkeys.sort_by{|d| m,y=d.split("/");[y,m]}
        @dropdataitem = Array.new
        @dropdataitem = DropSeries.new(1, @data3[0]["fields"]["@timestamp"])
        @dropdataitems = Array.new
        @ddhkeys.each do |dh|
            #@dropdataitems.push(DropSeries.new(dh[1], dh[0]))
            @dropdataitems.push(DropSeries.new(@dropdatahash[dh], dh))
        end

        @snort_data_hash = Array.new
        @ip_addresses = Array.new
        @snort_data = @esearch.search :q => ("snort"), :size => @query_size
        @snort_data = @snort_data["hits"]["hits"]
        @locations = Array.new

        if @snort_data.count > 0
            a= Array.new
            @snort_data.each do |f|
                break if f["_source"]["@timestamp"].to_time <  @ts
                ip_data = nil
                msg = f["_source"]["@message"]
                ip_data = msg.scan(/(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}/)
                a.push(ip_data[0]) unless ip_data[0].nil?
            end
            snort_res=Hash[a.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
            snort_res.each do |r|

                @snort_data_hash.push(SnortIP.new(r[0],r[1]))
                @ip_addresses.push(r[0].to_s)
                #@geoloc = Geokit::Geocoders::IpGeocoder.geocode(r[0].to_s) 
                @geoloc = Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(r[0].to_s)
                @ip_addresses.push(@geoloc.lat)
                location = Location.new(@geoloc.lat, @geoloc.lng, r[1], r[0])
                @locations.push(location)
            end

        end




        @data = @esearch.search :q => ("classification"), :size => @query_size
        @data = @data["hits"]["hits"]

        @data = @data.sort_by { |h| h["_source"]["@timestamp"] }.reverse!
        if @data.count > 0

            @filtered_data = Array.new
            @data.each do |d|
                break if d["_source"]["@timestamp"].to_time <  @ts
                @filtered_data.push(d)
            end
            if @filtered_data.count > 0
                a= Array.new
                @filtered_data.each do |f|
                    str_to_split = f["_source"]["@message"]
                    str = str_to_split
                    msg_data = str.split(%r{\[(Classification):+([\w\s]*)})
                        msg_data.each_with_index do |d,index|
                            classification_msg = msg_data[index + 1].to_s.squish if d.to_s == "Classification"
                            a.push(classification_msg) unless classification_msg.nil?
                        end

                end
                res=Hash[a.group_by {|x| x}.map {|k,v| [k,v.count]}]
                res.each do |r|
                    @widgets.push(Widget1.new(r[0],r[1]))
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

end
```

Comment: Have you checked if `@data3[0]["fields"]["@timestamp"]` and `DropSeries.new(1, @data3[0]["fields"]["@timestamp"])` are returning valid objects as expected?

Comment: What are `@data3[0]` and `@data3[0]["fields"]` returning? One of them is nil.

Comment: That's hurting my eyes ... so ... much ... instance ... variables ... aaaah!

Comment: You really need to refactor `index`: it is too big, there is code duplication, too many instance variables, `@dropdataitem` is assigned three different values in three consecutive lines, `@data` is assigned three different values in three consecutive lines, ...

Answer (score 0):

there are only 3 options for your error:

```
@data3 == nil
@data3[0] == nil
@data3[0]["fields"] == nil
```

you should check by yourself which one is the case